# xamarin forms master detail page flow direction in arabic

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail, titleview

I have a Master-Detail Page in my project, I've set the phone language to Arabic and everything is working fine the master page is on the right and the icon is on the right. But the thing is the TitleView (toolbaritems) are pushed a little bit to the right when the phone is set to Arabic. I tried this without Master-Detail page project and the TitleView is working fine and it is in the exact place.

With Master Detail Page:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppXamarin.Pages"
                  x:Class="AppXamarin.Pages.MasterMainPage" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False" FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage x:Name ="masterPage" FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MenuPage></local:MenuPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MenuPage Xaml file:

```
 <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}">
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="cart_Clicked"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="BadgeIconImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="cart">
                <Image.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="25" Tablet="35"/>
                </Image.HeightRequest>
                <Image.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="25" Tablet="35"/>
                </Image.WidthRequest>
            </Image>
            <Frame x:Name="BadgeFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="12" Padding="10,4" HasShadow="false" OutlineColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label x:Name="BadgeTextLabel" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="#FF0000"/>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Result:

[image: titleview1]

Without Master Detail Page:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}">
            <!--<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="cart_Clicked"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="BadgeIconImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="cart">
                <Image.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="25" Tablet="35"/>
                </Image.HeightRequest>
                <Image.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="25" Tablet="35"/>
                </Image.WidthRequest>
            </Image>
            <Frame x:Name="BadgeFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="12" Padding="10,4" HasShadow="false" OutlineColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label x:Name="BadgeTextLabel" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="#FF0000"/>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
        <!--</Grid>-->
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Result:

[image: titleview2]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding tells me you are trying to add toolbar items so you do not use titleView for that:

What you should be doing, on the other hand, is something like below

**C#:**

```
 this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem()
        {
            Icon = "BadgeIconImage",
            Command = YourCommand,
        });
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Icon="BadgeIconImage" />    
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

To understand Xamarin Forms Toolbar check [this](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/) guide by Adam Pedley

**Update**

I have a feeling that the padding that you are using on the Frame is what's pushing your View

```
 Padding="10,4"
```

Check this:

```
<Frame x:Name="BadgeFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="12" Padding="10,4" HasShadow="false" OutlineColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
```

Also could be the corner radius.

Comment: I was already having toolbar items, but the title view is more flexible and I can control them easily. The problem here is caused by the master-detail page, since in a new project the cart is placed regulary and no margins are added!!

Comment: Yes I checked it but the thing is the same padding and the same cornerradius value are placed in the first project, I tried as well to check it out it still the same !

Comment: But when it is right aligned then it doesn't matter what the left padding is do you understand my point?

Comment: Yeah I understand your point of view, and also I tried clearing all the paddings and margins and it is giving the same result  :'(

Comment: Then I am not sure what your issue is sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes I did it

manifest :

 <application android:label="Sanaap" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:supportsRtl="true">

MainView.xaml

<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Sanaap.App.Views.MenuView" 
             FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
             Title="Main">
```